# GridView Columns Keep Shrinking

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

The Gridview has many columns but they 'shrink-to-fit' inside the grid. The width of grid is 100%. But even without that, its the same. I would like the columns to expand, so that I can have a scrollbar to its parent div

```
<div style="width:100%; padding:1%">
 <fieldset style="border:1px solid gray;">
   <div style="overflow-x:scroll">
      <asp:gridview runat="server" width="100%">
      </asp:gridview>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

The columns are generated dynamically and can increase. As the grid doesnt expand horizantally, the scrollbar doesnt show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

add a fixed width to your gridview

```
<asp:gridview runat="server" width="2000px">
```

Comment: would that not be a bad option. If the cols increase to 2000px, they shrink after that. I checked this with 1100 px and thats what happened